# Androidplot legend icon shows differently on different devices

Tags: android, legend, androidplot

I am using AndroidPlot in my project and am trying to figure out why the same code leads to a different legend design on two phones.
On one phone the legend shows the line inside a black box, which makes it hard to see, on another phone I get a nice box in the line colour, which is the behaviour I want.

[Screenshot showing two legends side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y37aj.png)

Please ignore the overlapping legend text in the screenshot, that's the next problem I need to fix.

Comment: Interesting.  The line style is what I expect and I think is intended.  I use a black background so I have never seen the background colour mismatch.  I am thinking maybe a hardware accelerated rendering difference may be the cause.  What is it like on the simulator?

Comment: Same behaviour on the simulator, but you are right with the line style. It turns out that one screenshot was taken with a bar chart and the another one with a line chart.
I have meanwhile also figured out how to disable the background, `plot.legend.isDrawIconBackgroundEnabled = false` which get's rid of the black background. But what I haven't figured out yet is how to colour the background in the same way as the line, which would probably give me the desired behaviour. An easy to see block in the colour of the line.